# Backbone.js - models added to a collection are given a collection property causing recursion

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm experiencing a weird issue and I'm not sure if it is Backbone.js or my implementation?

```
// This code is within NavItem module.
// Nav is a Collection which is defined with the model NavItem.
var nav = new Nav();

// navConfig is just a JSON config object: 
//  e.g.  { text: 'Home', link: '/home', collection: [ { text: 'Home 
//            Sub Nav', link: '/home/sub-page' } ] } 
_.each(navConfig.items, function(item) {
    nav.add(new NavItem({
        text: item.text,
        link: item.link || null,
        // item.collection is an object 
        subNav: this._buildSubNavigation(item.collection)
    }));
}, this);

_buildSubNavigation: function(collection) {
    var subNav = null;

    if (collection) {
        subNav = new Nav();

        _.each(collection, function(subItem) {
            subNav.add(new NavItem({
                text: subItem.text,
                link: subItem.link || null
            }));
        }, this);
    }

    return subNav;
}
```

This code produces the following structure:

```
Object
    _byId: Object
    length: 2
    models: Array[2]
        0: Object
        attributes: Object
            icon: null
            link: "/home/sub-page"
            text: "Sub Nav"
        changed: Object
        cid: "c9"
        collection: Object
            _byId: Object
            length: 2
            models: Array[2]
                0: Object
                attributes: Object
                    link: "/home/sub-page"
                    text: "Sub Nav"
                changed: Object
                cid: "c9"
                collection: Object
                    _byId: Object
                    length: 2
                    models: Array[2]
                        0: Object
                            attributes: Object
                                link: "/home/sub-page"
                                text: "Sub Nav"
                            changed: Object
                            cid: "c9"
                            collection: Object
                                _byId: Object
                                length: 2
                                models: Array[2]
                                    0: Object
                                        attributes: Object
                                            link: "/home/sub-page"
                                            text: "Sub Nav"
                                            ..... and on, and on...
```

It looks to me like adding a model to a collection adds a 'collection' property to the model which contains the collection you added that model to? I'm not 100% sure what is going on here.

I know though that if in _buildSubNavigation, I initialise subNav as a vanilla JavaScript array '[]', then push to that rather than add to a Nav collection, then the structure is exactly what I expect:

```
[
    Object
        attributes: Object
        changed: Object
        cid: "c9"
, 
    Object
        attributes: Object
        changed: Object
        cid: "c10"
]
```

No collections in the NavItem objects. Does anyone understand this issue and know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably the property 'collection' is creating a recursive reference, but I can not determinate this with the information provided, Can you please include the JSON for "navConfig" and the code for "Nav" and "NavItem" please?

Comment: can you post a fiddle or a working example?

Comment: At the annotated source code (http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) you can see that if you add models to a collection, the model automatically gets a backreference to the collection.  Maybe that's your headache?